# Doctrine: two joins to the same table

Tags: join, doctrine-orm

I have a Characters table that has an ID and a name field.

> id    name
>   1    Gandalf
>   2    Frodo
>   3     Gollum
>   4    Samwise

I have a Matches table that has an ID, character1_id, and character2_id field.

```
id char1 char2
1    1     3
2    2     4
```

I'm trying to write a query that will join these and pull names according to the Matches table.

> Match 1 is Gandalf and Gollum
>   Match 2 is Frodo and Samwise

Here is my YAML

```
ORM\Dynasties2\Matches:
  type: entity
  table: proposals
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    manyToOne:
      character1:
        targetEntity: ORM\Dynasties2\Characters
      character2:
        targetEntity: ORM\Dynasties2\Characters
```

But I'm having no luck writing to it or reading from it.

I've tried this query, and have tweaked it a few different ways with no success.

```
$query = $this -> doctrine -> em -> createQuery ("SELECT a, b, c
        FROM ORM\Dynasties2\Matches a 
        JOIN a.character1 b
        JOIN a.character2 c

        ");
```

When I attempt to write to the entity, like

```
$new_match = new ORM\Dynasties2\Matches;
$new_match->setCharacter1($character1);
$new_match->setCharacter2($character2);
```

I get errors such as:

> Message: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given
>   Message: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

and

> Message: Argument 1 passed to ORM\Dynasties2\Proposals::setCharacter1() must be an instance of ORM\Dynasties2\Characters, string given

When I attempt to parse and display the query data, I get:

> Message: Object of class ORM\Dynasties2\Characters could not be converted to string

I have poured over the [Doctrine query documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html), but either I'm missing something, or failing to understand something.

(with CodeIgniter2, but I don't think that has any bearing on this)

Edit:

Here is my Matches entity

```
namespace ORM\Dynasties2;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ORM\Dynasties2\Matches
 */
class Matches
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var ORM\Dynasties2\Characters
     */
    private $character1;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Set character1
     *
     * @param ORM\Dynasties2\Characters $character1
     * @return Proposals
     */
    public function setCharacter1(\ORM\Dynasties2\Characters $character1 = null)
    {
        $this->character1 = $character1;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get character1
     *
     * @return ORM\Dynasties2\Characters 
     */
    public function getCharacter1()
    {
        return $this->character1;
    }
    /**
     * @var ORM\Dynasties2\Characters
     */
    private $character2;


    /**
     * Set character2
     *
     * @param ORM\Dynasties2\Characters $character2
     * @return Proposals
     */
    public function setCharacter2(\ORM\Dynasties2\Characters $character2 = null)
    {
        $this->character2 = $character2;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get character2
     *
     * @return ORM\Dynasties2\Characters 
     */
    public function getCharacter2()
    {
        return $this->character2;
    }
}
```

and characters:

```
namespace ORM\Dynasties2;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ORM\Dynasties2\Characters
 */
class Characters
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Characters
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

Edit:  more error output

I manually inserted some data into the Matches table in order to test the query.

I get the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class ORM\Dynasties2\Characters could not be
>   converted to string
>
> Filename: family/display_view.php
>
> Line Number: 23

Here is that view file:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {

$char1 = $row -> getCharacter1();
$char2 = $row -> getCharacter2();
//$target_turn = $row -> getTargetTurn();

echo "</br>You have proposed a match between " . $char1 . " and " . $char2 . ".</br>";
}
```

Line 23 is the 'echo'.

When I attempt to user a setter to write to the entity/table, I get the following:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Argument 1 passed to
>   ORM\Dynasties2\Proposals::setCharacter1() must be an instance of
>   ORM\Dynasties2\Characters, string given, called in
>   /path/applicationFolder/models/display_family_model.php
>   on line 76 and defined
>
> Filename: Dynasties2/Matches.php
>
> Line Number: 255

Here is line 76 of the model,

```
$char1 = $_SESSION["data_char1"];
$new_proposal->setCharacter1($char1);  // <-- line 76
```

Here is line 255 of Matches

```
public function setCharacter1(\ORM\Dynasties2\Characters $character1 = null) // <-- line 255
    {
        $this->character1 = $character1;
        return $this;
    }
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Argument 1 passed to
>   ORM\Dynasties2\Proposals::setCharacter2() must be an instance of
>   ORM\Dynasties2\Characters, string given, called in
>   /path2/applicationFolder/models/display_family_model.php
>   on line 77 and defined
>
> Filename: Dynasties2/Matches.php
>
> Line Number: 282

```
$char2 = $_SESSION["data_char2"];
$new_proposal->setCharacter2($char2); // <-- line 77

public function setCharacter2(\ORM\Dynasties2\Characters $character2 = null) // <-- line 282
    {
        $this->character2 = $character2;
        return $this;
    }
```

and

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string
>   given
>
> Filename: ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>
> Line Number: 1318

and

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string
>   given
>
> Filename: ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>
> Line Number: 734

and

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given
>
> Filename: ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>
> Line Number: 738

and

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMException' with
>   message 'Found entity of type on association
>   ORM\Dynasties2\Matches#character1, but expecting
>   ORM\Dynasties2\Characters' in
>   /path/applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:737
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /path/applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(639):
>   Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->computeAssociationChanges(Array, '5') #1
>   /path/applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(376):
>   Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->computeChangeSet(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata),
>   Object(ORM\Dynasties2\Proposals)) #2
>   /path/applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(661):
>   Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork->computeScheduleInsertsChangeSets() #3
>   /path/applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php(270):
>   Doctrine\ORM\UnitOf in
>   /path/applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   on line 737

Comment: Can you post your Character and Matches entity classes please.

Comment: A stack trace for the notices would be cool. It would help understanding when the issue happened

Comment: Do you mean var_dump(debug_backtrace()) or just more specific info from the default error message?  the backtrace is a mountain of data..

Comment: well, the stack trace would be useful, but I also see a problem with your YAML. Did you validate your mappings? Why aren't `character1` and `character2` indented correctly?

Comment: I don't know what a stack trace is.  I used the CLI to generate my entities from YAML.  And that appears to be a typo, which I'll correct.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that doctrine doesn't know which column to join characters to matches. The columns character1_id and character2_id need to be declared as joining columns, as doctrine will automatically assume a foreign key with target entity "ORM\Dynasties2\Characters" as characters_id.

Try adding the following to your YAML;

```
ORM\Dynasties2\Matches:
  type: entity
  table: proposals
  fields:
id:
  type: integer
  id: true
  generator:
    strategy: AUTO
manyToOne:
  character1:
    targetEntity: ORM\Dynasties2\Characters
    joinColumn:
        name: character1_id
        referenceColumnName: id
  character2:
     targetEntity: ORM\Dynasties2\Characters
     joinColumn:
        name: character2_id
        referenceColumnName: id
```

Comment: Hm, I don't think this is it.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#mapping-defaults  shows that even without those added columns, the code will default to those values.

Comment: @jeremy use the latest docs ;) http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#mapping-defaults